# AmpScript - RSS Feed in email using BuildRowsetFromXML()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've followed ET documentation regarding pulling data from RSS feed to email that can be found here:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/

I've created simple code:

```
%%[
SET @xmlTemp = ContentAreaByName("my contents\XML\XMLtest")
SET @xml = Replace(@xmlTemp, "content:encoded", "contentencoded")
SET @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
]%%

%%=Field(Row(@titles, 1), 'Value')=%%
```

It works fine when it's implemented in landing page but generates error when it's used in email. I tried to wrap output into TreatAsContent() but still nothing

Comment: Mateusz, can you provide RSS feed details? Also maybe extra bracket in your code  `%%=Field(Row(@titles, 1), 'Value')=%%` but not sure that is the issue.

Comment: Hey sure, http://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml

Comment: And You are right, there was an additional bracket but I removed it and I still can't make it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check `RowCount` of `title` before returning the field value.

```
   %%[
    SET @xmlTemp = ContentAreaByName("my contents\XML\XMLtest")
    SET @xml = Replace(@xmlTemp, "content:encoded", "contentencoded")
    SET @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
        If RowCount(@titles) > 0 Then
    ]%%
         %%=Field(Row(@titles, 1), 'Value')=%%
    %%[EndIf]%%
```

**Output**
`RSS Solutions for Restaurants`